# Cannot get any regression model to fit my heavily skewed data ( including parametric and non parametric regression), help!

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics

I am currently working with a large data set where I have measurements of energetic expenditure (Jkg.1dur.1) as my response. Originally I tried to use a mixed effect model with animal ID as the random effect but eventually scraped this when it seemed to show very little variance.
My data is heavily left skewed, and remains this way after a log transformation. I tried some Poisson and negative binomial regressions, but realized this wasn't really suited to my data (its integer rather than count).

I then tried a Gamma GLM with both inverse and log gamma. I shifted the data towards 0 by subtracting the minimum value (and adding 0.1 so there wouldn't be zeros), but also tried the models without this adjustment.
My models converge, but I have extremely low r2 and plotting the model residuals it shows they do not fit well. I am getting significant results which seem biologically meaningful but I do not trust my models.

My original data set was hourly energy measures which resulted in a data set of <70,000 points among 28 individual animals. I then decided to narrow this down to daily energy averages which is what I ran my subsequent models on. r2 improved slightly from 0.06 to 0.13 with these models but residuals remain poor.

I am at a loss as to what to try next? Is there sometimes just a case where you accept the your model does not fit well and your variables do not have the power to explain changes in the response?

(example model structure is;

```r
m9 <- glm(daily_ener  ~ Sex + scale(Age) + Food_period + scale(TRI) + 
          scale(sal_dist),
          data=df, family =Gamma("inverse"))
```

I would appreciate any help.

####################### EDIT BELOW

Apologies I did not provide enough information. The predictors TRI and sad_dist are both numeric variables. TRI is the average terrain roughness at a given location and sal_dist is the average distance to salmon streams. Food_period is a categorical variable with two levels, peak an non_peak.
I am interested to examine how intrinsic (sex and age) and extrinsic (food periods, proximity to salmon streams and terrain roughness) effect brown bear energetic expenditures.
My top model has so far always been the full model, with age significantly negative, sal_dist significantly positive, peak food periods significantly positive and males significantly positive.
[response data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaeKr.png)

[image: sample data]

[image: Gamma model fit]

Comment: It's hard to provide much useful advice without more details on your study and what you are trying to accomplish. What are `Food_period`, `TRI`, `sal_dist`? Might the effects of some depend on values of others? Is there a particular hypothesis you tried to test? What are the reported results of one or more of your models?  Please provide that type of information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can get deleted. Also, note that there is no reason to use `scale()` on continuous predictors; that can actually make it harder to interpret coefficient values intuitively.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I have now updated the question to include this information

Answer (score 4):

First, the choice of family and link in a GLM shouldn't start from the distribution of raw outcomes. The skew in the outcome (energy expenditure) values doesn't matter, if it's accompanied by corresponding skew in combinations of predictor values. The question is whether some combination of predictor variables can account for the distribution/skew of outcomes. There is no need to jump immediately to a GLM.

If the errors around the model predictions are well enough behaved, a simple linear regression might do. If errors around predicted outcomes are expected to be proportional to their values, then a prior log transformation of the outcomes and linear regression might work well.

Second, I wonder if you are under-fitting the data that you have. Your model only includes strict linear associations with outcome for each of your 3 continuous predictors. It's quite possible that the true associations are more complicated than simple linear relationships. Flexible regression splines can readily model more complex associations. There is no need to `scale()` the continuous predictors first; that removes any intuitive interpretation of regression coefficients in terms of things like a "decrease in energy expenditure per year of age."

You also could consider interaction terms among your predictors to make your model more flexible. For example, might energy expenditure depend in part on the combination of terrain roughness and distance to salmon rather than on each of them independently?

Third, you do have to take the repeated measurements on the same individuals into account in some way. The model that you show doesn't do that, so it ignores the correlations among observations within individuals and is likely to provide incorrect (probably over-optimistic) estimates of errors in coefficients. Mixed models are one way to do that, but there are others.

Fourth, I worry about reducing to daily averages. Within the same day there seem to be substantial differences in terrain roughness and distance to salmon. Also, you lose any ability to evaluate circadian patterns in the data. (Do you have information on sleep/wake patterns?) In general, it's not a good idea to throw data away. With 70,000 observations, over 2000 or so per animal, it should be possible to find any true associations of your predictors with outcome if you model the data flexibly enough to start.

I'd recommend stepping back a bit and looking into principles of flexibly modeling data via regression, then applying those principles to your data. Frank Harrell's [course notes](http://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and [textbook](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) discuss ways to do that. They also cover approaches besides mixed models for handling multiple observations within individuals, and quantile and ordinal regression methods that don't rely on assumptions about the distribution of outcome values given a set of predictor values. Those might work better than your GLM. Even if you end up using a GLM, many of the general principles for model building will apply.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response, this was very helpful.

Comment: I forgot to mention I already tried mixed effects models to account for potential individual variation, but the variance seemed low. After reading up on more flexible regression, and because many of my predictors do not have a linear relationship, I believe GAMM might be a good way to go.  However I am struggling to grasp which kind of spline would be best used in my case, I am still fairly new to r.